# Adding values in x64 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64

Does ADD EAX, EBX put to zero the 32 high-order bits of EAX if I just operate on the 32 low bits?

And what about ADD RAX, EBX? Is it possible? And if it is, are the 32 high-order bits of RAX preserved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ADD EAX, EBX` zeros the high 32 bits of *RAX*.  `ADD RAX, EBX` is not a valid instruction.

It sounds like you want to add a 32-bit value in `EBX` to a 64-bit value in `RAX`.  To do this, first you either zero-extend (`MOV EBX, EBX`) or sign-extend (`MOVSX RBX, EBX`), then add `RBX` to `RAX`.  (Use zero-extension if you are interpreting the value in `EBX` as unsigned, sign-extension if it is signed).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 32 bit `ADD` zeroes high order bits. `ADD RAX, EBX` is not possible. You can zero out the top 32 bits (for example by `MOV EBX, EBX`) and then use `ADD RAX, RBX` (note this possibly changes the top 32 bits of `RAX`)